# Replace character to newline symbol and display in Html.DisplayFor

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, razor

Before displaying my view in method of controller I replace character ; for newline symbol.

```
reservationHistory.ReservedHouses=reservationHistory.ReservedHouses.Replace(";", "\n");
```

In my view I display this field in that way.

```
@Html.DisplayFor(model => model.ReservedHouses)
```

However is not a good solution. Should I change symbol o new line in method `Replace` or use another method to display field instead of `Html.DisplayFor`?

Comment: `However is not a good solution` Why? What is the problem? What do you expect as a result? Why new line not `<br/>`?

Comment: I expect that each text between sign ';' will be in new line, I have tried with <br/>

Comment: Hint: if you split text by `;` then you will get a LIST of texts. And when you have a list you can use DisplayFor foreach text in the list.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
reservationHistory.ReservedHouses=reservationHistory.ReservedHouses.Replace(";", "\n");
```

Is fine althought you could swap `"\n"` for `Environment.NewLine`

Then in your view try doing the following:
  `@MvcHtmlString.Create(reservationHistory.ReservedHouses.Replace(Environment.NewLine, "<br />"))`